# Woocommerce order number

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need help how to change text in Woocommmerce

1. change text "Order Number:" & "Order Date:" into "Booking Number:" & "booking Date:"
2. how to change text "Billing Address" into "Address"only
   [order number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AvtY.jpg)

[billing address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4g9W.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [poedit](https://poedit.net) to edit the traduction of woocommerce